# Strapi admin page is just blank when opening. How do I fix it?

Tags: strapi

so I had strapi up and running and it worked fine.
I then wanted to install graphql and used `yarn strapi install graphql` it installed fine and I started strapi with yarn develop again, now when I try to open the admin panel i just get a blank black screen. The browser console logs a few errors:

`EvalError: call to eval() blocked by CSP`

```
Content-Security-Policy: Die Einstellungen der Seite haben das Laden einer Ressource auf eval blockiert ("script-src").
Source: ;(function r(e,t=!1){const o="6.0";let i…
```

English translation by me:

```
Content-Security-Policy: The pages settings blocked the loading of a ressource on eval("script-src").
Source: ;(function r(e,t=!1){const o="6.0";let i…
```

and my favorite:

```
TypeError: ye is undefined
```

[image]

Does anybody know what can I do to fix this?

Edit: I just tried uninstalling the plugin again with `yarn strapi uninstall graphql` but the problem ist still there

Comment: I now just put up a complete new instance of strapi and installed graphql and it works fine there, so no real fix but it works again for me for now